# Orchestrating Non-JavaScript Backend from Protractor Test

Tags: angularjs, testing, protractor

I am writing an application which has a LAMP backend, which provides a RESTful API. This API is consumed by an AngularJS front-end.

I have unit and integration tests for the API / GUI in isolation. Now I am expanding my test horizon to encompass a full front-to-back test suite.

I've been playing around with [Protractor](https://angular.github.io/protractor/), which has been extremely useful for the browser-based inputs for my front-to-back tests.
 However, I'm strugging to see how I can integrate this with the orchestration of the PHP backend.

---

Within the PHP integration tests, I have a set of utility classes that populate the system (i.e. database) with a pre-determined universe. For example; there is a pre-created user called "Bob", and an administrator called "Alice".

Between each integration test case, the entire universe is re-set to this base state, so that any interactions with Bob  & Alice in the test are re-set.

This is one example of the orchestration I would like to manage from Protractor. However, I cannot see an easy pattern to integrate with the PHP code which constructs the test universe.

After the initial population of the world, there are other orchestration tasks I would like to be able to execute to get the system into the desired target state; e.g. locking Bob's user account.

Without wanting to access the MySQL DB directly from the protractor code, how can I re-use my PHP logic and invoke the business logic from Protractor?

I could offer RESTful orchestration URLs. But this seems dangerous, as it would pose a serious risk if ever released to production.

---

There are a number of suggestions on other StackOverflow questions (e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20518687/angular-e2e-tests-affecting-database)) which suggest using Mocks. These seem to completely miss the mark; given protractor is designed for front-to-back tests.

---

Comment: Is it possible to interact with PHP code via command line? What I mean is basically run a PHP script from Protractor (node.js) before a test, then run the test itself, the run another PHP script to remove all test data.

Answer (score 0):

**Business Logic**

We have done that but in a different way. We have written that business logic in our API service code that it will check what kind of environment you are trying to reset. If your target environment is your local codebase or test environment then it will offer your Rest `/reset` apis.

```
if(environment === qa || environment === local) {
// Allow reset service
} 
else {
// No reset service
}
```