# e2e testing in angularJS within a cleverstack context and a mock api

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-e2e

Creating my first mock api is turning out to be very unsuccessful.

I followed two solutions:

[AngularJS & Jasmine HTTP Backend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21577718/angularjsjasmine-httpbackend-not-working-as-expected)

[Mock HTTP Backend e2e Tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16807130/mock-httpbackend-in-angular-e2e-tests)

And my implementation:

```
describe('[user story] The user would like to capture contractor drilling information', function() {

    beforeEach(module('contractor_drilling'));

    var $httpBackend;

    beforeEach(inject(function($injector) {
        $httpBackend = $injector.get ('$httpBackend');

        $httpBackend
            .when ('GET', '/api/Block/Getblock/1')
            .respond ({
                id: 1 ,
                block_number: '11/11/11'
            });
    }));

    afterEach (function () {
        $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation ();
        $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest ();
    });

    it ('should returns block data', function () {
        $httpBackend.expectGET ('/api/Block/Getblock/1');
        $httpBackend.flush ();
    });
```

Can anyone please give me an example on how to achieve this mock-API in an **Cleverstack** context.

The errors i'm getting:

**TypeError**: object is not a function @ `beforeEach(module('contractor_drilling'));`

**ReferenceError**: inject is not defined @ `beforeEach(inject(function($injector) {`

Now I read that you need to include **angular-mock.js** for my ReferenceError to be solved, but isn't cleverstack including this file somewhere already? or is it a setting to turn on or off in cleverstack.

I'm new to cleverstack and quite new to AngularJS so a good thorough explanation would be very helpfull.

Thanks.