# Mocking rest calls in functional e2e protractor tests in angular 4 project

Tags: angular, protractor, angular-mock, angular-e2e, angular-test

We have a huge project and we have written a lot of test cases to cover a lot of real scenario user behavior in our e2e functional test cases.

As the test goes on, it makes a lot of rest calls to complete the test cases. When we cover different browser in sauce lab it multiplies 5-9 times.

What I want is to mock all the rest calls so that there will not be any real calls to the actual server but internally it will be handled. its for functional e2e test not unit test as we mocked all unit tests using jasmine `spyOn`.

I have explored `json-server` and `$httpBackend` of protractor. son-server did not fit as it does not handles app post, put, delete calls well. in case of $httpBackend

I have gone through [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16807130/mock-httpbackend-in-angular-e2e-tests) and its  for andularJs app not angular app and also its all about single rest call mocking for angularJs not for all rest calls.

Also looked this angularjs [multi mock for angularjs](https://github.com/wongatech/angular-multimocks) and its also for angularjs not angular and looks like this changes the original rest url for query parameter.

Answer (score 7):

Mocking network calls is not supported yet by Protractor for Angular 2+ applications. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36457515/7170335) and the [corresponding issue](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/3092) on github.

Personnally, I used [ng-apimock](https://github.com/mdasberg/ng-apimock) plugin to mock all network calls to the backend with a proxy.

It works really well and is simple to configure. Just follow the configuration for Angular application [here](https://github.com/mdasberg/ng-apimock/blob/master/ANGULAR_CLI.md)

Comment: How to configure it for angular 7? The example provided is for angular 1 using server.js file . how to achieve the same in angular 2+

Comment: The server is written in node.js, just launch it with: "node server.js"

Comment: Can someone please show usage of ng-apimock plugin for protractor.